# how can I write a program in python that compares a given word with a text?

Tags: python

So i need to write a function in python, where it compares a input word with a text and gives me the word 'closest'(with the smallest distance) to the input word.

With distance I mean for example the words 'the' and 'to' have distance 2 because I need to change 2 letters.

(PS: I just started learning coding so I don't really know much about this)

These 2 codes is what I already have and I've tested these so it's correct

This is to get to words out the text:

```
def get_words():
return re.findall(r'\w+', open('big.txt').read().lower())
```

Then I wrote this to put the words in a dictonary with the number of times the word occurs:

```
d=dict()
for token in get_words():
   if token in d:
       d[token]+=1
   else:
       d[token]=1


for key in d:
   if d[key]>5:
       print(key,d[key])
```

My problem starts with letting the word compare with the text
This is what I have:

```
if distance(word_dict, word) <= 1:
     word = input('give a word')
     return (word_dict)
else:
  return ('no match')
```

Comment: did you try something ? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm trying some things but I can't find the right code ;(

Comment: Are you looking for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance?

Comment: So post what you did, and explain where is the exact problem with the code you've done

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like :

```
>>> w1="the"
>>> w2="to"
>>> len([i for i in w1 if i not in w2])
2
```

to compare two words... Then :

```
>>> txt1="this is the sentence"
>>> w1="to"
>>> txt1.split(" ")[min([len([i for i in w2 if i not in w1]) for w2 in txt1.split(" ")])] 
'the'
```

`"the"` is the closest word to `"to"` in the text `txt1`. this work is there is only one space between each word in your text... 
so you should adapt it to your text to obtain a list of words from the text and then compare each element of this list with your "input word".

Answer (score 0):

you need to rate every word in your text so first you split the text to words and then rate them by proximity to the given word

Now all you need to do is to output the best rated word

You still have to figure out what to do if there are two words with the same rating but that is the basic logic

Good luck